# What causes every DNS to resolve to 11.11.11.11 during outage?

Tags: networking, router, dns

For the past couple months I've been encountering random disconnects from the internet, typically once a day. They last no more than 30 seconds (and can be really annoying while playing games or watching stuff).

Frustration aside, I've recently been able to identify when the internet is about to die momentarily - while playing games I get this huge lag spike, after which the connection is fine again for a few seconds, and then it really dies.

I decided to exploit this "behaviour" to look around and see what happens and I've noticed something *really* strange during the outages - when pinging ANY hostname (google.com, aaa.com, blah.blah etc.) it shows up like this:

[image: nslookup and ping returning 11.11.11.11 in cmd]

As the picture denotes, I use Google's public DNS (8.8.8.8) and not my router's default gateway/ISP's DNS servers.

What could cause the host names to be resolved to this IP address during the network outage?

Comment: What's your ISP?  Do you use DHCP to connect or a static IP?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage As far as I know, my ISP issued us a static IP. All LAN devices use DHCP - we're behind a router after all.

Comment: Does this happen on *all* devices? Or was it only on your computer?

Comment: I've definitely seen ISP-provided broadband modems (really combination modems/home-gateway-routers/Wi-Fi-APs) switch modes when they detect the broadband link go down. They start providing stub services locally so your LAN still functions until the broadband link comes back up. I wouldn't be surprised if something like that is happening here.

Comment: I'd suspect your firewall, but it could be the modem. DNS traffic is distinct and easy to modify mid-stream, so your modem forging responses is well within the realm of possibility. either way, the component responding is somewhere in the network stack, but this is not default windows behavior, so firewalls, network card drivers, servers on the LAN, and gateway equipment are all likely candidates. I'd say the firewall on your PC is the most likely culprit, followed by the modem, then the nic drivers (only likely if you are using less standard drivers).

Comment: @AdiGerber , I'm not certain , but if you rent your modem from your ISP , you can probably ask them to send a replacement.  It should not be having network outages frequently, and it should not be making DNS changes.